# Does attacking a zombie in the nether cause the zombie pigmen to become hostile?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I created a portal in the nether and it led into an abandoned mine.  I explored the abandoned mine  for a while before re-entering the Nether where I found a number of skeletons and zombies had wandered in.  One of the zombies attacked me, so I attacked back and I think the surrounding zombie pigmen became hostile (I died before I knew what was going on).

Can someone confirm that this actually does happen?  Is this a bug or is it intentional? (ie the zombie pigmen see their overworld counterparts as kindred spirits or something)

I was on snapshot 14w06b

Comment: I recall something like this in an Etho's video.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's do this with ***SCIENCE***

I'm going to test this by bringing a zombie to the nether and punching him around some Pigmen. If this hypothesis was true, then the Zombie Pigmen should kill me instantly because that's what they do.

I did exactly this, making extra sure to not hit the Pigmen, and reproduced exactly this result. It seems that Zombie Pigmen still take care of their Zombie brothers. I'm not sure if this is intentional or not, but I doubt it's a bug, since Zombies and Zombie Pigmen are entirely separate entities.

Pigmen are deadly, and some of them probably picked up your stuff. Good luck.

Comment: I don't remember this behavior at all before. I'll dig through the changelogs and see if this was added at some point.

Comment: Apparently, pigmen share some of the Zombie's code, which is why we have baby Pigmen and Chicken Jockeys in the nether.

Comment: upvote for SCIENCE!

Comment: I just did some testing in 1.9, and it seems that Zombie Pigmen don't care about zombies at all now.

Comment: @MrLemon I will review this and update

Answer (score 0):

Not always. I had three pigmen within 10 to 20 blocks, but they did not become aggressive when I hit a zombie, however I had previously hit all of the mobs before dying so there may be some flag that prevents a new wave of agro.

I have fought a few more zombie hoards with pig men around but none became aggressive. Even when they were standing 2 or 3 blocks from the zombie I hit with an arrow. However a hoard of zombies attacked after I hit it, and the pigmen behaved as normal once I hit one of them after killing the zombies.

I am Snocrashes Hermit Chunk Challange in 1.9